Godot: using MeshDataTool on scenes from Blender
I'm new to Godot, coming from Unity, and am trying to do some in-code editing of some meshes that I've created in Blender, but I'm struggling to find the best workflow to access my mesh data from these imported meshes.
I'd like to use MeshDataTool to read and transform vertex and edge data from my meshes. This is working correctly if I import each mesh individually as a Wavefront (.obj) file, and then access the mesh data through the MeshInstance3D node.
mesh = $MeshInScene.mesh mdt = MeshDataTool.new() mdt.create_from_surface(mesh, 0)
However, I would like to be able to create a MeshDataTool for an object imported as a .blend or .glb scene. Is there a way to access the imported meshes (or a specific mesh) in these scenes, or do I have to import meshes individually as .obj files to use the MeshDataTool?
